# UWP Windows 10 как вызвать GoBack

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

C# UWP Windows 10

Собственно сабж: 
В Windows Phone 8 приложениях можно было использовать `NavigationManager`. Как программно вызвать `GoBack()` в приложениях Windows 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переход на другую страницу совершается примерно так же как и в WP8:

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SettingsPage));
```

Для того чтобы вернутся назад можно сделать так:

```
Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        if (rootFrame.CanGoBack)
        {
            rootFrame.GoBack();
        }
```

Обратите внимание, что кнопку "Назад" окна можно отобразить или скрыть так:

```
SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility =
        ((Frame)sender).CanGoBack ? AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible : AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Collapsed;
```

ну и можно добавить обработку события нажатия на эту кнопку:

```
SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += OnBackRequested;
```

Comment: Это я знаю и использую. А что если нету доступа к `rootFrame`  и нужно имитировать нажатие кнопки назад

Comment: Как так нет доступа к rootFrame? Посмотрите код:
    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
Текущее содержимое окна - это rootFrame

Comment: А если был другой `Content`. Кнопка назад вызывает `OnBackRequested` в App.cs. Там может быть своя обработка которая подменит окна (напр. окно ввода ПИН-кода на SplitView ) А значит у текощего окна `rootFrame.CanGoBack = false` - всегда

Comment: Как программно реализовать GoBack() я написал, а вот по поводу подмены окон не совсем вас понимаю.

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Смысл в том, что это будет работать только если текущее окно является фреймом и в нем производилась навигация, а это далеко не всегда так. Такой подход имеет право быть (в некоторых случаях) но он не вызывает `OnBackRequeted` так как это делает хард-кнопка..